# CSS Div Chevron inconsistencies with firefox

Tags: css, firefox

I have this code for a css chevron. It works well in chrome but in firefox, it has [these](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kjKpp.png) separations in the div where in [chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zYPYo.png) these don't really exist.

```css
.sidenavChevron {
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 6px 6px 0 0;
    content: '';
    height: 12px;
    width: 12px;
    top: 15px;
    right: 20px;
    display: inline-block;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    transition: var(--delay);
    position: relative;
    color: #f1f1f1;
    float: right;
}
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a box shadow instead:

```css
.sidenavChevron {
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 6px 6px 0 0;
    height: 12px;
    width: 12px;
    top: 15px;
    right: 20px;
    display: inline-block;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    transition: var(--delay);
    position: relative;
    left: 30px;
}

.sidenavChevron2 {
    box-shadow: 6px -6px 0 currentColor;
    height: 18px;
    width: 18px;
    top: 15px;
    right: 20px;
    display: inline-block;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    transition: var(--delay);
    position: relative;
    left: 40px;
}
```

```html
<span class="sidenavChevron"></span>
<span class="sidenavChevron2"></span>
```

which gives you a different kind of problem:

[image: A thin visible shadow on the other side]

which you can hide with a clip or equivalent:

```css
.sidenavChevron {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 25.46px;  /* √2 * 18 */
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    width: 16.97px;  /* √2/2 * (18 + 6) */
}

.sidenavChevron::before {
    box-shadow: 6px -6px 0 currentColor;
    content: '';
    height: 18px;
    left: -9.5px;  /* -18 + √2/2 * (18 - 6) */
    position: absolute;
    right: 20px;
    top: 50%;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    transform-origin: right top;
    transition: var(--delay);
    width: 18px;
}
```

```html
<span class="sidenavChevron"></span>
```

… how about a nice SVG instead?

Comment: Guess I'm just going to use an SVG instead. Was mostly experimenting. Thanks for the answer!